# Titles of movie

Tags: prepositions, titles

Why normally in movie title prepositions are removed? for exemplo: "I know what you did last summer" shouldn't be "I know what you did **in the** last summer."

Comment: Even in normal conversation, "last summer" would usually be said with no article.

Comment: "I know what you did last summer" is perfectly valid conversational English.

Comment: English can use time expressions adverbially without requiring prepositions.

Comment: Sorry, but no native speaker would say "in the last summer" here.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Some preliminary research, as we customarily expect, should have turned up numerous films with prepositions in their titles. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help]. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Your premise is wrong. Expressions of time starting with "this", "next" or "last" do not usually take either a preposition or an article.

Answer (score 1):

"last" forming part of adverbials of time does not take a preposition or the definite article **unless**:

1. it is followed by some postmodifier that restricts the meaning of the noun phrase:

   - I know what you did **(in) the last summer we spent together**. (The adverbial is actually more idiomatic without "in".)
2. it refers to the twelve months immediately preceding the time of speaking:

   - I've lived  here **for the last year** (= for the last twelve months).